# X3D format of 3d model to OBJ format in js

Tags: javascript, converters, 3d-model, x3d, viro-media

Does exist some js library for converting x3d format to obj? Or how will be difficult to create the converter in js, if it does not exist? I tried convert x3d to obj by online converter, but I didn't see in OBJ file same data like it was in X3D format.

Thank you for your advices!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CAD Exchanger](https://cadexchanger.com/) to convert files from one to another like .x3d to .obj.